# What is the geometric realization of the configuration simplicial space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, configuration-space

Take a path-connected space $X$ and consider the family of non-empty, ordered configuration spaces $(\text{Conf}_{\bullet+1}(X))$. This collection of spaces forms a semi-simplicial space with face maps $d_i =$ forget the $i$-th point. This can be seen as a subspace of the family of cartesian powers $(X^{\times (\bullet+1)})$ with the same face maps (here, there are also degeneracies).

It is a know fact that the realization of the latter simplicial space is contractible : it is the same proof that the simplicial construction of $EG$ is contractible for a group $G$.

One could construct degeneracy maps for the configuration simplicial space by considering Fulton-MacPherson compactification of these configuration spaces (when $X$ is a manifold), and the existence of a non-vanishing vector field on $X$ (to choose how to put an additional point "infinitesimally close" to another).

My question is : do we know the homotopy type of the (fat) realization $|\text{Conf}_{\bullet+1}(X)|$ ? Is it weakly contractible as it is the case for $|X^{\times (\bullet+1)}|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wahl considers a framed analog of this question in the case of surfaces in ["Homological Stability for mapping class groups of surfaces"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.4476.pdf). On page 28, she shows this semisimplicial object is contractible when the surface has boundary components. The dimension and the framing do not appear to play a role in the argument, though I have not carefully checked. From this fact she then deduces the case of a closed surface which also does not seem to use these facts.

More general statements can be found in section 11.2 of Randall-William's ["Resolutions of moduli spaces and homological stability"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.4278.pdf) and I believe in the case the manifold is framed, you can play around with tangential structures to directly deduce the result you are after from the version with framings.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and the references !